# Problem solving $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$, Riemann and Lebesgue

Tags: calculus, integration

How can we solve $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$ for Riemanian integration and Lebesgue integration mode?

Comment: This is an indefinite integral!

Comment: Are there any bounds you're forgetting, or is this actually indefinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the change of variables $x=\tan t$ to get

> $$ \int \cos^2 t\, dt .$$

I think you can finish it.

**Note:** The following identity is useful

> $$ \cos(2x)=2\cos^2 x - 1 .$$

Comment: @Maryam: Have you studied Riemann integration and Lebesgue integration?

Answer (score 0):

A method worth looking at (now I do not know its ramifications for Riemannian Integration or Lebesgue Integration, someone else will need to explore that) is good old partial fractions from Calc 2:

$$(1 + x^2) = (1 + ix) (1 - ix)$$

$$ \int{\frac{1}{(1 + x^2)^2}} = \int{\frac{a_1}{1 + ix}} + \int{\frac{a_2}{1 + ix}} + \int{\frac{a_3}{1 - ix}} + \int{\frac{a_4}{1 - ix}}$$

Such that:

$$a_i = u_ix + v_i$$

The challenge then is to simplify the expression you get (which may involve a variety of complex logarithms) into something clean involving, preferably, inverse trig functions.

But of course, if Lebesgue and Riemman integration is only defined over $R$ then this is of no use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial fraction expansion that may be useful

$$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2-1}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Riemannian integral is easily obtained as 
$$\frac{1}{2} atan(x) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

Hope this helps
BTW: I followed the usual approach to partial fractions and then regrouped the terms into something nice.